# Sum of sets of measure zero

Tags: measure-theory

Let $A$ and $B$ be two subsets of $\Bbb R$ of measure zero. Is it true that the Minkowski sum $A+B = \{ a + b \mid a \in A, b \in B \}$ has measure zero as well? I think so but I can't prove it. The usual trick with the convolution $\mathbf 1_A \star \mathbf 1_B$ does not seem to lead to something interesting.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpfull putting the definition of Minkowski sum.

Comment: @Lierre I have a question. Actually, it is not completely clear to me if the set is even measurable in the first place (?). It might be trivial though but it is not clear to me.

Comment: @matgaio Added !

Comment: @Marvis — Well, it's not clear to me neither ;)

Comment: For those interested in history, Lebesgue seems to be the first person to have proved this result. See p. 285 of Lebesgue, *Sur la recherche des fonctions primitives par l'integration*, [**Atti della Accademia Nazionale dei Lincei, Rendiconti, Classe di Scienze Fisiche, Matematiche e Naturali**](http://books.google.com/books?id=MF1IAAAAYAAJ) (5) 16 #1 (1907), 283-290.

Comment: @DaveL.Renfro Thanks for this !

Comment: @Lierre if $A, B \subseteq \mathbb{R}$ are measurable, then $A + B = m(A x B)$, where $m \colon \mathbb{R}^{2} \to \mathbb{R}$ is the continuous function $m(x,y) = x+y$. In particular, as the continuous image of the measurable $A \times B$, the set $A+B$ is 'analytic'. It is a basic fact in descriptive set theory, that analytic subsets of Polish spaces are universally measurable.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming I understand Minkowski sum correctly, this is not the case. For example, if $A$ is the Cantor ternary set and $B$ the set of opposites (additive inverses) of elements of the Cantor ternary set, then $A+B=[-1,1]$.

Comment: Awesome example !

Comment: @Lierre: Glad you like it! Even simpler to prove is that $A+A=[0,2]$, from which the result I quoted follows readily.

Comment: Probably this example is even in your textbook...

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand what you mean by "set of opposites of the Cantor ternary" !

Comment: @Fardad: I mean $B=\{-x:x\in A\}.$

Answer (score 13):

If $A$ is the set of real numbers such that in their proper binary expansion, the even terms are $0$, and $B$ the same with odd numbers, then $A$ and $B$ have measure $0$ but their sum is the whole real line.

Comment: Even simpler, thanks !

Comment: Why set A has measure zero. I couldn't see. Can someone help me?

Answer (score 2):

The following i think works too: Let $A=\cup_{n\in \mathbb{Z}^+\cup\{0\}}\left(n+\frac{1}{2}C\right)$ and $B=\cup_{m\in\mathbb{Z}^-}\left(m+\frac{1}{2}C\right)$, where $C$ is the ternary cantor set. Then, since $\frac{1}{2}C+\frac{1}{2}C=[0,1]$ (which is not hard to prove), it would follow that $A+B=\mathbb{R}$, with $\mu(A)=\mu(B)=0$.

Can someone comment on this solution?

Comment: Yes, this is an extension of Cameron Buie's answer.